# C++ - Get latest release of a GitHub project

Tags: c++, qt, github-api

I have a program that uses a set of files stored in a GitHub project.

I would like to check the latest release version of that GitHub project and download those files if it's newer than local.

Does anyone know how to check release version and download from (using QT C++)?

My program is done in Qt 5 (https://github.com/bq/QssWeb2Board)

Comment: So you want to initiate a git command from your C++ program? Then you probably want to use a library, for example, libgit2 (https://libgit2.github.com/). You could also call an installed git executable using `QProcess`, but then you have to deal will all kinds of output parsing.

Comment: @pschill I was thinking about using GitHub API

Comment: When using the GitHub API, you need to build your commands as http request and handle the result. Dont you think it is easier to use a library whose only purpose is solving the exact problem you have?

Comment: @pschill yes. That's a great library. It just seems to much to my goal. But I will give it a try. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the commented lib and doing some digging around I found an answer. Here it is the main code. Thanks.

```
QUrl url("https://api.github.com/repos/" + owner +"/" + project + "/tags");
qInfo() << url.toString();
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
QNetworkAccessManager nam;
QNetworkReply * reply = nam.get(request);

timeout=false;
timer->start(5000);

while(!timeout){
    qApp->processEvents();
    if(reply->isFinished()) break;
}

if(reply->isFinished()){
    QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
    return json[0]["name"].toString();
}else{
    return QString("Timeout");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above may return an empty string.

In such case, the line `return json[0]["name"].toString();` should be `return json.object()["name"].toString();`

Cheers,